# Latest stable version of solr

Tags: solr

**solr**

Now i am using solr4. I need to migrate solr to latest version.
 Which solr version is latest and stable?

> - What are the conditions i need to check for migration?
> - How can i merge this version to latest version?
> - Which version can u prefer for me?
> - any migration tool is available for this migration?

I think about solr 6.3.0
Is it stable ? 
What are the manger difference in solr 4 and 6 ??

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading you really have to choices:

1. Reindex. This is the easiest (and you should have a way to reindex on request anyway, but some use cases makes reindexing hard, since Solr could be your primary datastore), most flexible and gives you the best end result.
2. Do a version-by-version upgrade, going from each version that supports the old index format to the most recent version that supports that format, then repeat until you're on your target version of Solr. Since old index versions are usually readable through each main version tree (I think), you'll have to go 4 -> 5 -> 6. You can use the [IndexUpgrader tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexUpgrader+Tool) to help with this, and as you can see at the bottom of that page, Jan made [a tool that automates 4 -> 5 -> 6 for you](https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex).

The differences are far too many to really list, please [refer to the Changelog for each release](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_3_0/changes/Changes.html). In particular there's a world of difference regarding cloud / cluster support between 4.x and 6.x, and there's a lot of new features, such as streaming expressions.

Upgrading the schema is a matter of going through the datatypes you're using and checking if they've changed definitions (ints vs tries, for example). You'll probably be OK with just minor changes. The default schema factory has changed from the classic index schema to the managed schema, so if you want to keep editing the schema.xml as you're used to, you'll have to change to the ClassicIndexSchemaFactory in your configuration.